# How enable tcpreplay fragroute engine

Tags: ubuntu, tcpreplay

I have installed tcpreplay and before that installed libdnet libevent and fragroute but the fragroute engine is disable and i can not use --fragroute option in tcprewrite. how can i enable the fragroute engine?

Answer (score 1):

More details.  What version of tcpreplay? 3.5.0beta1 fixes compile issues on Debian/Unbuntu related to this kind of problem. Did you make sure you have the development headers for libdnet installed as well?

bug fix was here: http://tcpreplay.synfin.net/ticket/499

When you run configure, does it say at the end if it will enable fragroute or not?